# Logical IP not reachable from OEL 6.6

Tags: networking

I am a newbie to OEL 6.6 - 64 bit i am facing one weird problem with network, please find following;

- Destination server is having 2 IPs - Logical and Physical.
- From OEL 6.6 if i ping physical IP then its working fine, but when i ping logical IP no response at all for ping (not even destination not reachable or request timeout).
- If i do the traceroute to logical IP its showing me as next hop to switch and then next one to physical IP.
- The OEL 6.6 has default gateway as switch, from switch i am able to ping logical as well as  physical IP of destination server.
- Firewall is off on OEL 6.6 server, as the physical IP is reachable from OEL, it means ping is allowed on the destination server.

With this it is very clear that there is some issue at server side configuration (OEL 6.6), I hope my problem statement clear to you .

Need help to resolve it

Thanks in advance

BR,
Veerat

Answer (score 0):

On debuggin configuration on destination server following was find which helped to fix the issue;

The Logical IP interface on destination server was not configured with gateway as server physical IP, hence packet was not reaching to Logical IP.